# Identity Server 4 with JWT. Different expire date on different endpoints

Tags: jwt, identityserver4

I’m using Identity Server 4 for authentication on a Dotnet core 2.0 WebAPI project. The API is used by multiple web- and iOS/Android applications.

Today we’re using JWT as the access token and the standard JWT expire flag (that is set to login time + 1 hour) to determinate whether or not a JWT has expired. Now we would like to change some of the endpoints in the API that still require the user to log in to receive a JTW but on these endpoints the JWT should be valid for many days.

Is it possible to handle multiple JWT’s for a single login, or should this be handled with a custom attribute in the JWT to handle the more secure endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens comes in 2 favours, self-contained and [reference](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/topics/reference_tokens.html#), you can reference tokens and take benefit of [introspection endpoint](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/endpoints/introspection.html) for extra check. There is a built-in [cache](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html#supporting-reference-tokens) available which you can set its `CacheDuration` based on API security level. 
You are also able to customize the introspection response via [IntrospectionResponseGenerator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/Default/IntrospectionResponseGenerator.cs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I’m not sure why reference token would help in this case. My understanding is that `CacheDuration` will be set to the token itself and will expire at the same time for all endpoints. I want to be able to have different expire date depending on if the endpoint is considered as a more secure endpoint or not.

Comment: The access token lifetime is not settable per API on IDS4. Its possible on some other providers though https://auth0.com/docs/dashboard/guides/apis/update-token-lifetime. Using reference tokens is suggested solution to achieve what you need in ur business. Refresh token is a good example to see how it works.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I’ll look more into how refesh tokens works. Thanks for your help!